# Disable Button if nothing is selected at the dropdown

Tags: angularjs, button, angularjs-ng-disabled

The button should be disabeled, when nothing is selected at the dropdown. How can I achieve this?

```html
<select size='1' id="action" ng-model="ak.action">
    <option value='1'>RED</option>
    <option value='2'>BLUE</option>
</select>

<div>
    <button type="button" ng-Click="ak.save()" >SAVE</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This should be under angularjs tag and not angular :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `ng-disabled="!ak.action || ak.action.length == 0"` on the button.
Although the `select` will always have a selected item in your case...

```
<select size='1' id="action" ng-model="ak.action">
        <option value='1'>RED</option>
        <option value='2'>BLUE</option>
</select>

<div>
    <button ng-disabled="!ak.action || ak.action.length == 0" type="button" ng-click="ak.save()" >SAVE</button>
</div>
```